# get_field Not Working Django Rest Framework Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In serializers.py

```
class WordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    synonym = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(max_length=100), allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Word
        fields = ['word', 'id', 'user', 'definition', 'synonym', 'sentence', 'user', 'currently_studying']
```

when the original model has synonym value of `synonym1\nsynonym2\nsynonym3`, the synonym value in the serializer should return `['synonym1', 'synonym2', 'synonym3']`. How can I do that?

Comment: why would you expect that the method gets called? Only defining a method does not make it get executed when you create an instance of the class it belongs to. You have to override a method that gets called and place your method inside. but dont forget the super() method. Or you call it manually in your view. Just tell us when it should be called and maybe add your view, then we can help you.

Comment: I updated the question and the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work for the synonym field because it is not possible to change the type of value from string to list but we can add a custom field to our json output. Here is an example. the key in the json output is "synonym_list" if you want to change it just change the name of the SerializerMethodField() and the method name ( get_ + new_name ) and change it in the fields list (Meta class) accordingly:

```
class WordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    synonym_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Word
        fields = ['word', 'id', 'user', 'definition', 'synonym', 'sentence', 'user', 'currently_studying', 'synonym_list']

    def get_synonym_list(self, obj):
        return obj.synonym.split("\n")
```

Does that work for you?